# How can I copy specifically the timestamp from one column and update it on another column that has another date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table names MY_TABLE. There are three columns in it i.e ID, CREATED_TIMESTAMP and DUE_DATE.

| ID | CREATED_DATE_TIME | DUE_DATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11/15/2023 08:06:07 | 12/15/2023 00:00:00 |

I need to copy the timestamp value e.g "08:06:07" from "CREATED_DATE_TIME" and update it on the DUE_DATE_TIME column so that the value on DUE_DATE_TIME should become like this :
12/15/2023 08:06:07 after getting updated.

Note: Both the columns have different dates. I only need to copy the timestamp not the date. I need to do it for all the records on that table.

Answer (score 1):

One option to do it is using date math combined with TRUNC() function :

```sql
UPDATE tbl 
SET DUE_DATE = TRUNC(DUE_DATE)  + (CREATED_DATE - TRUNC(CREATED_DATE))
WHERE  ID = 1
```

Sample:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", 
                 To_Date('11/15/2023 08:06:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "CREATED_DATE",
                 To_Date('12/15/2023 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "DUE_DATE"
          From   Dual
        )
--  S a m p l e    S Q L:
Select  To_Char(CREATED_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "CREATED_DATE", 
        To_Char(DUE_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "DUE_DATE", 
        To_Char(TRUNC(DUE_DATE)  + (CREATED_DATE - TRUNC(CREATED_DATE)), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "COMBINED_DATE"
From tbl
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
/*    R e s u l t :
CREATED_DATE        DUE_DATE            COMBINED_DATE      
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
11/15/2023 08:06:07 12/15/2023 00:00:00 12/15/2023 08:06:07   */
```

**NOTE**: DATE datatype in Oracle defines century, year, month, day, hour, minute, second - first 4 is date part and last 3 time part - TIMESTAMP is another datatype. More about it [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6381/index-en.html).

Answer (score 1):

Below statement updates the data as required,

```
update my_table 
set due_date_time = to_timestamp(to_char(trunc(due_date_time), 'mm/dd/yyyy') || ' ' || to_char(created_date_time, 'hh:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss');
```

Select statement for validation:

```
select 
    id, created_date_time, due_date_time,
    to_char(created_date_time, 'hh:mi:ss'),
    to_timestamp(to_char(trunc(due_date_time), 'mm/dd/yyyy') || ' ' || to_char(created_date_time, 'hh:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss')
from 
    my_table;
```